# Typescript lint-fix command not working after checking for typescript lint issues? Need to know a workaround or a fix

Tags: typescript, eslint, tslint, tsc, typescript-eslint

When I check for issues with linting in typescript code by running `npm run lint` it gives out the linting issues but when I try fixing the issues using `npm run lint:fix`, it gives out an error stating:

```
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 2
    npm ERR! express-server@1.0.0 lint:fix: `sudo npm run lint --fix`
    npm ERR! Exit status 2
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the express-server@1.0.0 lint:fix script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

scripts used in the package.json are :

```
"scripts": {
    
    "lint": "./node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json --exclude 'node_modules/**/*.{j,t}s'",
    "lint:fix": "sudo npm run lint --fix",
}
```

Comment: Try `npm run lint -- --fix`